# Getting Each Colour of Pixel From my LockBits

Tags: c#, graphics, pixel, imaging, lockbits

I have a program which gets every pixel in an image and outputs them into a text document. The problem is that it just throws them in there are as numbers and it looks rather ugly.
e.i. " 37 37 37 36" I wish to display them much like the GetPixel function does.
e.i. [A=255, R=4, G=255, B=131]. My current code is...

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("Space big.jpg");

Rectangle bmpRec = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height); //Creates Rectangle for holding picture

BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(bmpRec, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb); //Gets the Bitmap data

IntPtr Pointer = bmpData.Scan0; //Sets pointer

int DataBytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height; //Gets array size

byte[] rgbValues = new byte[DataBytes]; //Creates array

Marshal.Copy(Pointer, rgbValues, 0, DataBytes); //Copies of out memory

bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

StringBuilder Pix = new StringBuilder(" ");

Stopwatch Timer = new Stopwatch();

pictureBox1.Image = bmp;

        StringBuilder EachPixel = new StringBuilder("");

        Timer.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < bmpData.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bmpData.Height; j++)
            {
                // compute the proper offset into the array for these co-ords
                var pixel = rgbValues[i + j * Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride)];
                Pix.Append(" ");
                Pix.Append(pixel);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is just the debugger visualizer attached to the Color struct.  You are already forcing the bitmap to be interpreted as a 32bpp image so an int[] instead of a byte[] is the appropriate array type.  Now each element is a single pixel.  You can convert it to a color with Color.FromArgb(int).